# Energy of a partial stationary wave

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves

Suppose that I superimpose two waves travelling in a string of area of cross section $s$ and density $\rho$. The two waves are
$$
y=8\sin(\omega t-kx)\quad \text{and}\quad y'=6\sin(\omega t+kx).
$$
I need to find the energy between two consecutive nodes. The resultant wave ($y+y'$) can be taken as a combination of a pure stationary wave and a pure travelling wave:
$$
y+y'=12\sin(kx)\cos(\omega t)+2\sin(\omega t-kx).
$$
The energy between two consecutive nodes can be given to be the sum of energies due to the travelling wave and the stationary wave. The energy due to the travelling wave is ${\scriptsize\frac{1}{2}}\rho s\omega^22^2(\pi/k)$ [here $k=2\pi/\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is the wavelength] and the energy due to stationary wave is ${\scriptsize\frac{1}{4}}\rho s\omega^2(12)^2(\pi/k)$. On adding these two energies, we get $38\rho\omega^2s\pi/k$. Another way of doing this is by adding the energies due to the original two stationary waves: ${\scriptstyle\frac{1}{2}}\rho s\omega^2(8)^2(\pi/k) + {\scriptstyle\frac{1}{2}}\rho s\omega^2(6)^2(\pi/k)$, which is equal to $50\pi\omega^2s/k$. This gives us the right answer. Why is the first approach wrong?

Comment: There is a pending close vote on this question as a [homework-like question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and/or a [check-my-work question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583). Since offering bounties interrupts this process, I have refunded your bounty so normal close vote review can take place. You may offer the bounty again if the question is still open in a few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a "top writer" at all but want to propose a simple explanation.

Let function $y(x,t)$ describes string oscillations. If oscillations are small enough, then the string's energy is
$$
E[y(\cdot)] = \int \left(\alpha\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}\right)^2(x,t) + \beta \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)^2(x,t)\right) dx
$$
with coefficients $\alpha$ and $\beta$ related to the physical properties of the string. It is obvious from this expression that the energy of superposition $y_1+y_2$ of two arbitrary waves $y_1$ and $y_2$, in general, is not equal to the sum of waves' energies:
$$
E[y_1(\cdot) + y_2(\cdot)] \neq E[y_1(\cdot)] + E[y_2(\cdot)]
$$
At the same time, if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are two independent ($y_2\neq const\ y_1$) monochromatic waves, then $E_{1+2} = E_1 + E_2$.